# How to make a nasalized schwa [ə͂] in textipa?

Tags: fonts, linguistics, tipa

I could not find anything online. I tried `\~\textipa{@}` but that produced only a tilde before a schwa. Any help on resolving this probably simple issue would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `\~\tipaschwa` or `\textipa{\~@}`?

Answer (score 11):

Just put the `\~` inside the scope of the `\textipa` command:

```
\textipa{\~@}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use `\~` within `\textipa{}` thus: `\textipa{\~{@}}`

[image]

You should use the diacritic commands within "the IPA environment" (which is the generic term for the IPA groups and environment in the `TIPA` manual). All of your IPA stuff really belongs in the IPA environment. This will allow consistency of font and encoding, but it's also the only way a command like this can work.

Comment: Ooooh, sorry I was a bit late, didn't notice Alan Munn had already jsut about said it all!